# What class do I use to "new" a command in Avalonia?

Tags: c#, windows-10, .net-7.0, avaloniaui

What do I have to *new* to instantiate a command in Avalonia? I don't want to use any libraries for that. No ReativeUI, no CommunityToolkit etc. I know I need some methods that will implement the `Execute` method, but just in order to start with commands, what do I need to use?

```cs
using System.Windows.Input;

public class HomeModel
{
    public HomeModel()
    {
        OpenBrowserCommand = new TODO();
    }

    public ICommand OpenBrowserCommand { get; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good implementation of `ICommand` can be found in ReactiveUI's [`ReactiveCommand`](https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/commands/). If you've created your application using the [Avalonia MVVM Application](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/tutorials/todo-list-app/creating-a-new-project#net-core-cli) template then this will be available by default. See the `ReactiveUI` documentation for more information.

```
public class HomeModel
{
    public HomeModel()
    {
        OpenBrowserCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create(RunTheThing);
        // or
        OpenBrowserCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create<string>(RunTheThingWithParameter);
    }

    public ICommand OpenBrowserCommand { get; }

    private void RunTheThing()
    {
        // Code for executing the command here.
    }

    private void RunTheThingWithParameter(string parameter)
    {
        // Code for executing the command here.
    }

}
```

`ReactiveCommand` is a Reactive Extensions and asynchronous aware implementation of the `ICommand` interface. It is created using static factory methods which allows you to create command logic that executes either synchronously or asynchronously. The following are the different static factory methods:

- `CreateFromObservable()` - Execute the logic using an `IObservable`.
- `CreateFromTask()` - Execute a C# [Task Parallel Library (TPL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming) Task. This allows use also of the C# [async/await](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async) operators.
- `Create()` - Execute a synchronous `Func` or `Action`.
- `CreateCombined()` - Execute one or more commands.

To create a new command in Avalonia **without using any external libraries**, you can create a new class that implements the `ICommand` interface, which requires two methods to be implemented: `Execute` and `CanExecute`:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Func<object, bool> _canExecute;

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        _execute = execute ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);

    public void Execute(object parameter) => _execute(parameter);

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged() => CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Then use it in your code:

```
public class HomeModel
{
    public HomeModel()
    {
        OpenBrowserCommand = new RelayCommand(p => { /* some code here */});
    }

    public ICommand OpenBrowserCommand { get; }

    private void RunTheThing()
    {
        // Code for executing the command here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh! There is no ready to use command yet and one needs to implement the interface?  So be it, I hadn't expected this kind of plot twist.